# Run R script if sub-directory changes

Tags: r, cron, filesystems, windows-task-scheduler

Currently, in my organization, we collect data from participants on a weekly basis. This data then gets put into a sub-folder within the folder "Data". The sub-folder reflects what sport our participants play. For instance, inside "Data" might be "Hockey" and "Soccer", each with several .csv files inside. We then create .rmd reports for each participant after each data collection session.

Right now, this is done through an R script where we specify the participant and their sport, and this script runs the .rmd script - and a rmarkdown report is created into the "reports" folder. However, we now have 100's of participants and this process is not scaleable to a large operation.

Therefore, I plan on using some scheduling package (taskscheduleR or cronR) to create my rmd reports at the end of each day.

Ideally, I would like R code that checks within the folder "Data" to determine if any sub-folders have changed (most likely increased in size due to an addition of a new .csv folder) - if a sub-folder changes, then the rmd reports are created for the file in that sub-folder.

Checking for sub-folder size changes and executing the script on only those has served to be a large challenge. If anyone has some insight/expertise on this, it would be much appreciated. Alternatively, if there is a better method in achieving this goal that I have not considered I am open to suggestions!

My apologies for the large post and the somewhat vague question, please let me know if you would like more detail.

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: May you check for modified date with `file.info` instead of checking file size?.

Comment: Thanks @Ric , This is a smart idea! I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

As per the commented suggestions:

Using CronR, I have created a solution. Note that here, the analysis of data is to create an .rmd report.

'''

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

#what rmd file to render?
rmd <-"rmarkdown file path"

#list of folders in processed data folder
parent_folder <- "parent folder path"
list_folders <- list.dirs(parent_folder)[- 1]

#for each folder, check date modified - if last modification date was today, create new reports
for (folder in list_folders) {
  
  mod_date <- as.Date(format(as.POSIXct(file.mtime(folder)),"%Y-%m-%d"))
  
  #-----
  if(mod_date == Sys.Date()){
    
    Data <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE) %>%
      lapply(read_excel, sheet = Excel_sheet) %>%
      bind_rows 
    final_unique_names <- unique(Data$names)
    
    
      #-----    
      for (i in final_unique_names) {
      
        
        #rmd report with unique params
        rmarkdown::render(rmd, 
                          params = list(name = i,
                                        ),
                          output_format = "pdf_document",
                          output_file=paste0("path to output"))
      }
    }
}
```

'''